# How to get array of strings from Map<String, Any?> in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I read a yaml file to a map in kotlin (Map<String, Any>)
this yaml file contains a list of strings, eks:

```
...
myStrings:
  - string1
  - string2
  - string3
...
```

I read the map as follows:

```
private fun readWithGson(jsonPath: String): Map<String, Any> {
    val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(FileReader(jsonPath))
    val gson = Gson()

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, Map::class.java) as Map<String, Any>
}
```

When `println(map)`, it contains:

```
...
myStrings=[string1,string2,string3]
...
```

How can get the array of strings?

```
map["myStrings"] as Array<String>
```

produces a `java.lang.ClassCastException`

Comment: Because it is an ArrayList and not an Array!

Comment: Use `.toTypedArray()`. Using `as` is for casting, not converting.

Comment: You've edited the question and suddenly the results are entire different than last time. What stands out is that you are using Gson, which expects a `JSON` format to parse a `yaml` file.. Not sure how that even works but you'll likely need a yaml parser like [snakeYAML](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml)

Comment: I am sorry for editing the question... The provided answer did work. I noticed I had some code which was not changed, when I allready had started to edit the question... I forgot all about it... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stored as an (Array)List. So just get and use it as a List:

```
val myStrings = map["myStrings"] as List<String>
```

If you need to edit the list later on you can cast it to MutableList:

```
val myStrings = map["myStrings"] as MutableList<String>
```

If you *really* need it to be an Array, though for most cases you don't, you'll have to convert the List to an array:

```
val myStringsArray = myStrings.toTypedArray()
```